# Can't alter mysql column default timestamp value to lowest possible value?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I'm trying to alter an existing MySQL column in a specific table.
I want to change the column, which is of type timestamp, to the earliest possible value as the default value.

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.40

According to the [MySql Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html), timestamp range value can be:

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

But when I try to alter the table column to '1970-01-01 00:00:01' I get an error.

Here's the query that fails:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY COLUMN latest_login_date timestamp default '1970-01-01 00:00:01' NOT NULL;
```

Gives:

`Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'latest_login_date'`

Also tried other values a few seconds later - still no good.
The first value that worked for me was this:

```
ALTER TABLE account_social_integration MODIFY COLUMN latest_login_date timestamp default '1970-01-01 02:00:01' NOT NULL;
```

Can someone explain please?

Comment: as Timestamp is in date format, you're trying to pass a string value which is not accepted. try something like casting the date string, like this:  ALTER TABLE account_social_integration MODIFY COLUMN latest_login_date timestamp default DATE('1970-01-01 02:00:01') NOT NULL;

Comment: What is your mysql timezone settings ?

Comment: that will only work if your timezone is <= UTC. the fact that `1970-01-01 02:00:01` worked would indicate you're in UTC +2 Hour timezone. Your profile suggests israel, israel is UTC +2 hours

Comment: That makes sense. I checked mysql timezone by running `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);` and it shows +3 (not +2). It doesn't explain why a timestamp with +2 hours still work, unless it's not a valid check